# Complex XML Parsing in R

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I am trying to parsing a xml file that is nested.

```
<GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT>
     <HEADER compName="California" dateCreated="2018-08-07">
      <COMP_INFO>
    </HEADER>
     <COVERSHEET>
      <ESTIMATE_INFO eName="MATTHEW_ANDERSON" iName="Matthew Anderson" priceList="MAY18" laborEff="Restoration/Service/Remodel" claimNumber="01" policyNumber="00000000000" typeOfLoss="Hail" deprNonMat="1" deprOandP="1" deprTaxes="1" onsite="1" recipientsXNAddress="California_BD" carrierId="111111" estimateType="Structural"/>
      <ADDRESSES>
       <ADDRESS type="Property" street="123 Street Cr" city="Idaho Falls" state="ID" zip="00000" primary="1"/>
       <ADDRESS type="Home" street="123 Street Cr" city="City" state="ID" zip="00000"/>
      </ADDRESSES>
  </COVERSHEET>
</GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT>
```

I am trying to extract information like iName and price list.

For my end product I was hoping to have a dataframe where the information looks like one row that only includes the following:

```
compName  |  dataCreated  | iName  |  Type  | Street|  | State
```

There is not much documentation of how to extract with multiple data inside one segment.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML files can have a lot of nesting which can make them difficult to translate directly to a data.frame. I think the easiest way to extract these files are to reshape them to something more tabular with `xslt`.

Using your sample data

```
library(xml2)
xml <- read_xml('<GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT>
     <HEADER compName="California" dateCreated="2018-08-07">
      <COMP_INFO/>
    </HEADER>
     <COVERSHEET>
      <ESTIMATE_INFO eName="MATTHEW_ANDERSON" iName="Matthew Anderson" priceList="MAY18" laborEff="Restoration/Service/Remodel" claimNumber="01" policyNumber="00000000000" typeOfLoss="Hail" deprNonMat="1" deprOandP="1" deprTaxes="1" onsite="1" recipientsXNAddress="California_BD" carrierId="111111" estimateType="Structural"/>
      <ADDRESSES>
       <ADDRESS type="Property" street="123 Street Cr" city="Idaho Falls" state="ID" zip="00000" primary="1"/>
       <ADDRESS type="Home" street="123 Street Cr" city="City" state="ID" zip="00000"/>
      </ADDRESSES>
  </COVERSHEET>
</GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT>')
```

We can define an xslt to transform the data into an html table

```
xsl <- read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT">
    <html>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>compName</td><td>dateCreated</td>
    <td>iName</td><td>type</td><td>street</td><td>state</td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="//ADDRESS">
    <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="../../../HEADER/@compName"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="../../../HEADER/@dateCreated"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="../../ESTIMATE_INFO/@iName"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@street"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@state"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>')
```

And I made it an HTML table just so I could use `rvest::html_table` to turn it into a data.frame. That would be done like this

```
library(xslt)
library(rvest)
data <- xml_xslt(xml, xsl) %>% html_table(header = TRUE)  %>% .[[1]]
#     compName dateCreated            iName     type        street state
# 1 California  2018-08-07 Matthew Anderson Property 123 Street Cr    ID
# 2 California  2018-08-07 Matthew Anderson     Home 123 Street Cr    ID
```

Comment: thank you, I was also looking for smth like this. In you code you forgot `library(xslt)`. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks. Updated the missing library.

Comment: Future readers, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) is a special-purpose, declarative language (sibling to XPath) and can be used beyond R.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried running what you provided and am getting an error with xml_xslt  not found.

Comment: Also, would you recommend using python for this instead of R?

Comment: Sorry, I realized R didn't run my line to instand xslt. It worked. Thank you